# What IM do you use to login into Microsoft Office Communicator?

Tags: microsoft-office

I've used Pidgin, but it hasn't worked 100%, so maybe you know about something better...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used to use `pidgin-sipe` in Pidgin. The same plugin apparently works through empathy too.

I say "used to" because I'm not longer in an environment where I need it, not because I found anything better. As far as I know, it's the only plugin to tackle the problem.

In short, I think you're left trying get your problems fixed (report a bug), rather than jumping boat to another project... Which is probably healthier for both of you.

Comment: I use Pidgin and `pidgin-sipe` currently for Communicator 2010

Comment: I am using the same. Not perfect, especially for managing my online status, but i don't know of anything better.

Comment: looks like pidgin-sipe is really the best option

Comment: The only option from what I can see (short of running the native client through WINE or a VM)

Answer (score 2):

`pidgin-sipe` works very well, make sure your office communicator server and proxy server (if necessary) is set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As it was said, you can use either `Empathy` (installed by default on UBuntu) or `Pidgin` (available in the Software Centre), as long as you install the following plug-in which works for both: `pidgin-sipe`.

There is a detailed explanation of the steps on this forum thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1291311

Look for Huygens' (myself) posts.